# Flashcards to remember all Ingress glyphs

Tags: data-request, games

Ingress glyph hack is a mini-game where you have to remember a number of patterns.
The patterns are shown very quickly, and then you have to redraw them.
Example of a pattern:

[image: Ingress glyph]

There are not that many patterns, so most players just remember them all and stick "names" to each one, to be able to remember the sequence.

Is there a flashcards deck (ideally in Anki format) to associate patterns with easy-to-remember names?
I am **not looking for a flashcards app**, just for flashcards data.

[The Glyphtionary](http://glyphtionary.com/) is a database trying to gather all glyphs, so it could be used as a starting point to build the deck, but I don't think the images are under an open license.

Comment: Hey Nicolas. This question might be better suited for softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SamtheBrand: This question is about data. SR is for software. See http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/a/230/754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just created an anki deck based on the ingress.tv glyphs. It is available for download as an apkg here.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/745sda96j070fyg/ingress.glyphs.apkg?dl=0

One of the differences is my deck contains known 2-5 string sequences as well (well, as shown on ingress.tv). Note that the deck you have found is based on glyphtionary - I previously used this as well but found it had some minor errors (I believe they have been corrected now)now.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found an Anki deck that does exactly that:

https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/551048448

I has 117 glyph image+name flashcards. Free.
Usable with Anki/AnkiDroid/AnkiMobile on PC/Android/iOS.